# Does gcc always do this kind of optimization? (common subexpression elimination)

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

As an example, assume that the expression `sys->pot.atoms[item->P.kind].mass` is evaluated inside a loop. The loop only changes `item`, so the expression can be simplified as `atoms[item->P.kind].mass` by defining a variable as `atoms = sys->pot.atoms` before the loop. Do modern compilers like gcc perform this kind of optimization automatically (if optimization is enabled)? And is it reliable regardless of the number of expressions like `atoms[item->P.kind].mass` existing inside a loop?

Comment: Unless `sys`, `sys->pot` or `sys->pot.atoms` is volatile, GCC should optimize it in this way, yes (probably even at `-O1`). If I am thinking about introducing a temp local variable for this, it's usually just for readability, not because the compiler is not smart enough. However, if you disable strict aliasing through compiler settings, it might behave differently depending on which pointers you are modifying between calls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is a very common optimisation called [Loop invariant code motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination), also called hoisting or scalar promotion, often performed as a side effect of [Common subexpression elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination).

It is valid to compute `sys->pot.atoms` just once before the loop if the compiler can ascertain that neither `sys` nor `sys->pot.atoms` can be modified inside the loop.

Note however, as commented by *Groo*, that if `sys` or `sys->pot` or `sys->pot.atoms` are specified as `volatile`, then it would be incorrect to compute it only once if the expression `sys->pot.atoms` is evaluated multiple times in the loop body or expressions.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the formal name of this optimization? Something such as "optimization by substitution" so that I can search and learn more?

Comment: @apadana: It is called [“hoisting.”](https://compileroptimizations.com/category/hoisting.htm) The expression that does not vary in the loop is hoisted out of the loop.

Comment: @apadana: Answer amended with links to further info.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very common optimization.

> And is it reliable regardless of the number of expressions

No, because optimizations is not something you can rely on happening in general. The C standard says nothing about it, so it's up to the maker of the compiler to give guarantees or not. But that's nothing you really do for the optimizer. The optimizer has a "best effort" approach, and a missed optimization is often treated like a flaw rather than an actual bug.

EDIT:

From discussion in comments, I found it useful to mention that just because a certain optimization was performed, that does not guarantee faster code. For instance, the benefit of loop unrolling is that the test in the loop does not need to be performed every iteration. But on the other hand, longer code can be less cache friendly. So asking if it's guaranteed that a certain optimization is performed or not does not really give any useful information.

> I always wonder where I should do optimization myself, and where I should sit relax and leave it to the compiler.

That's very hard to know in advance. Guys like Linus Torvalds can basically see the assembly code in their head just by watching the C code, but for us mere mortals, it comes down to benchmarking and profiling.

Before even considering micro optimizations, perform these checks

1. Make sure that the code you're about to optimize actually is a bottleneck
2. Make sure you're using a good algorithm
3. Make sure the code is cache friendly

Comment: I always wonder where I should do optimization myself, and where I should sit relax and leave it to the compiler.

Comment: @apadana It's actually quite simple. Only optimize manually if you have a performance issue.

Comment: In a scientific simulation, each run may take several days. So one always likes further optimization. And as you said optimizations are not part of the language; different compilers may perform differently.

Comment: @apadana True, but that's shifting perspective. The relevant question is if the code is as fast as possible/fast enough. Not if the optimizer performed a certain optimization or not. There are two major things to think of when optimizing C. 1) Make sure you're using a good algorithm. 2) Make sure your code is cache friendly.

Comment: Note that “flaws” are bugs, at least depending on the specification of the compiler. A bug is a deviation between software and its specification. The specification for a compiler does not just say what the “observable behavior” of the resulting program must be with respect to the programming language but also says something about what optimizations are performed. A failure to perform a certain optimization might or might not meet that specification. (And, where a formal specification is not maintained, some sense of whether the flaw meets desired quality serves in its stead.)

Comment: I understand and agree that a good algorithm and being cache friendly are more important. I'm just saying that doing the kind of optimizations that this question is about (whether manually or by compiler) also does matter. Otherwise, compilers wouldn't try to optimize code.

Comment: @apadana Yes, but optimizations made by the compiler is essentially free. That's the big difference.

Comment: @apadana When they can be done automatically and without destroying the readability or design of the code, it's worth using them even if the performance only increases by 0.01%. That's not the case when you do manual optimization.

Comment: For my code, the optimization by compiler decreases running time by at least 10%. Perhaps I'm a bad programmer! So you think this kind of optimization should be left to the compiler. Many thanks. :)

Comment: @apadana Some of the optimizations has a huge impact. Others are very minor. My point is that as long as they come for free, they are worth it. I'm not saying that you should leave it to the optimizer, nor am I saying that should optimize manually. That's a decision for you. But optimizing without profiling and measuring is almost always completely pointless. Very often the performance bottlenecks are not where you think they are. But I might also point out that it is a skill to write optimizer friendly code as much as it is to write cache friendly code.

Comment: One thing that is good to know is that manual optimization often makes it pretty hard for the compiler optimizer to do it work properly. The cleaner the code, the easier it is for the optimizer.